# In CnosDB After move vnode, compact vnode report vnode not found

Tags: move, cnosdb

```
version cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 6776285b45d1441cff5896a345b45f4f03b85522
```

//first move vnode

public > move vnode 7 to node 2001;

Query took 3.655 seconds.

---

//then compact the vnode

public > compact vnode 7;

422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"050015", "error_message": "vnode not found: 7"}

Comment: It works in version 2.3.4